# Root name in Windows

Tags: windows

I know this is stupid but I'm really unsure about the answer. I don't know the root name of my computer.

I'm setting public and private key pair to log in a machine as this [link](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/logging-in-with-an-ssh-private-key-on-windows/). It has this line:

> Click Connection > Data in the left-hand navigation pane and **set the
>   Auto-login username to root**.

My C:\ folder path is like: "C:\Users\USER", and the name of the computer is Tet. My public key has a line of `USER@Tet`.

Is my root name is "USER" ? Or where can I see it?

Please help me out. Thank you in advance!

[image: I need to fill in the red area]

Comment: I think you are confusing user roles, user name and computer name.
The question is OT here, I suggest you to check this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/504136/root-vs-administrator-vs-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's asking to set auto login for the computer you are connecting to (presumably a Linux machine with root login access) not the computer you're connecting from (the Windows machine).

Comment: Please see the image I just added in. Is that some username I can make up?

Comment: No.  It looks like you're SSHing into a Rackspace Linux machine.  I didn't read the whole tutorial in detail but it's unlikely that that machine is set up for root access from a SSH client.  Most likely what you should enter is the credentials you would use to normally log onto that machine then when you need to have root access you can issue the commands with 'sudo.....'.  If  you don't know what a Linux login for the machine is you've got a big problem or if the whole sudo thing confuses you you probably need to back off and spend a little time learning some Linux basics.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is the name that already set up in the machine that corresponding to my account, right?